# How to check existence of the CVS tag?

Tags: scripting, shell, tags, cvs

I need to write a shell script to check the existence of certain CVS tag in the repository, and do different things depending on the result. So hence is my question: How to check for CVS tag existence and parse the result in shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you have all the permissions/credentials, you can check for a cvs tag in the following way:

```
cvs status <filename> | grep <tagname>
```